# Evaluation of the right-hand-side of the formula raises an error in R and don't know what to do

Tags: r, events

I am doing event study following guide. but when I run this code,

```
mod_twfe = feols(crime_rate ~ i(time_to_treat, treat, ref = -1) + ## Our key interaction: time × treatment status
                    violent_crime + homicide + rape_legacy + robbery + aggravated_assault + property_crime + burglary + larceny + motor_vehicle_theft | 
                   sid + year,                          ## Other controls   ## FEs
                 cluster = ~sid,                          ## Clustered SEs
                 data = Pcrime)
```

it says

```
Error in feols(crime_rate ~ i(time_to_treat, treat, ref = -1) + violent_crime +  : 
  Evaluation of the right-hand-side of the formula raises an error: 
  In NULL: in i(factor_var = time_to_treat, var = treat, ref = ...:
 In argument 'ref', the value doesn't match any value of 'factor_var'.
```

In this case, what should I do?

Comment: Did you check whether `is.data.table(crime) == TRUE`?

Comment: it says FALSE. What should I do?

Comment: It is hard to know without the code or data, but a start might be something like `crime = as.data.table(crime)`

Comment: yes it worked. but data.table was not a solution to avoid the error of ```feol``` function. :(

Comment: According to the documentation, `ref=...` must refer to one of the levels in the factor `treat`. It uses that level as the reference level. Is `treat` a factor?

Comment: Also, the documentation suggests that the numeric variable is the first argument and the factor variable is the second argument, but the error message suggests the opposite. You could try swapping the arguments.

Comment: Difficult to do more without access to your `Pcrime` dataset.